# Determine ideal $I(V)$ for variety $V(x+y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals, affine-varieties

I want to determine $I(V)$ (the ideal of $V$) for $V(x+y)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=-y\}$.
It is defined as $I(V)=\{f\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]:f(a,b)=0 \forall (a,b)\in V\}$. So e.g. we have $f_1,f_2,f_3\in V$ for $f_1(x,y)=x+y, f_2(x,y)=x^3+y^3, f_3(x,y)=x^3+y$. But I do not really get the pattern... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:
$f_3$ is not in $V$!

Comment: I don't understand, why $f_3$ should be in $I(V)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, you are totally right! $f_3$ is not in $V$! Is it correct that $I(V)=\{x^n+y^n\}$?

Comment: Edit: $n$ has to be odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: the polynomials $x^n + y^n$ you already found, all have a nice decomposition:

$$(x^n + y^n) = (x + y)(x^{n-1} - x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2 - \ldots - xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$$

Similiarly we find that $x^2 - y^2 \in I(V)$ thanks to the decomposition

$$x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x-y)$$

Second hint: knowing that both $x^3 + y^3$ and $x^5 + y^5$ are in $I(V)$ you get for free that $x^5 + 2x^3 + 2y^3 + y^5$ is as well.

All in all $I(V)$ is a lot larger than you think (in the comment).

Comment: So is $I(V)$ some kind of $(x+y, x-y)$? But how can I exculde something like $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: You are almost there... $(x + y, x - y)$ is a bit too big, because $x - y$ is not in $I(V)$. After all the point $(x = 1, y = -1)$ is in $V$ but evaluating $f(x, y) = x - y$ on that point yields $f(1, -1) = 2$, and $2 \neq 0$.